# Can I trace LDAP / AD queries using the OpenTelemetry Agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, open-telemetry, aws-xray

I have a Spring Boot application deployed on AWS ECS Fargate. Besides the main container, I also have a AWS OTEL Collector as a sidecar container.

I'm using the [AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry - Instrumentation for Java](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-java-instrumentation/releases/latest/download/aws-opentelemetry-agent.jar) to send data to X-Ray.

My application connects to several external resources including OpenLDAP and AWS Directory Service. I can see traces and service map diagrams on CloudWatch for all of my external resources except for LDAP connections & queries to OpenLDAP and AD.

I can't trace these requests on X-Ray.

Is the OpenTelemetry Agent enough or do I need to use the SDK to manually trace every OpenLDAP / AD query?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the OpenTelemetry Agent enough or do I need to use the SDK to manually trace every OpenLDAP / AD query?

Unfortunately, neither the AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry, nor the OpenTelemetry Agent for Java [(which it is based on)](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-java-instrumentation#introduction), support LDAP instrumentation out of the box.

You will need to manually instrument the application to trace your LDAP/AD requests.